# IIS URL Rewrite for Laravel Application Not working for multiple URI Segments

Tags: regex, laravel, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am having a scenario that if URL  doesn't contain anything in URI segment then no need to rewrite to index.php but if contains then rewrite it.

For Example: http://www.example.com/ or http://www.example.com No Rewrite Rule Required

But if URL is http://www.example.com/homepage or http://www.example.com/user/1 or http://www.example.com/edit-user/123/456
then it should be rewrite to index.php

I tried below.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="custom rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"  />
</rule>
```

It is working for  http://www.example.com/ and  http://www.example.com/homepage but showing 404 for others pages.

The URI segments are dynamic and it can be multilingual.

Technologies used IIS, PHP (Laravel)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, it will match all kinds of URIs whether dynamic or multilingual.

```
 <rule name="custom rule">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*" />
                   </conditions>
                </rule>
```

[Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdFvj.png)

[Fail request tracing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StPtf.png)

If this rule is only used for some URIs like user or edit-user, maybe this rule is more suitable.

```
<rule name="custom rule">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="user/(.*)" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="edit-user/(.*)" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
```

Comment: for the above http://abcexample.com/  is also going in this condition

Comment: Do you mean that abcexample.com also rewrite to example.com/index.php?You can set server variable HTTP_HOST.     <serverVariables><set name="HTTP_HOST" value="www.example.com" /> </serverVariables>

Comment: still same issue. the one rule i mentioned in my question is working fine except multiple request uri

Comment: Could you please describle issue more detailed? The rule I provided has tested and success.Does it fail when you apply it? The best way to judge uri is in conditions.

Comment: May I know if your problem is solved? If my answer is helpful to you, please mark this answer so that it can help others with similar problems.